# Is the infinite decimal fraction $1.23456...n$ irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

How to prove that the number

$ 1.23456\dots n$ is an irrational number?

The number consist, of course, of natural numbers in increasing sequence.

Comment: Rational numbers are periodic. Your number has stretches of 0s longer than any potential period.

Comment: It equals to $10C$ where $C$ is the [Champernowne Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html) and is known to be a transcendental number.

Answer (score 9):

A rational number is a number of the form $\dfrac n m$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers.  A question is: what does the decimal expansion of a rational number look like?  Consider a concrete example: $\dfrac n m = \dfrac{55}{148}$.  To find the decimal expansion, do long division:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
& & & 0 & . & 3 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 2 & \ldots  \\[12pt]
148 & ) & 5 & 5 & . & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
    &   & 4 & 4 &   & 4 \\[12pt]
    &   & 1 & 0 &   & 6 & 0 \\
    &   & 1 & 0 &   & 3 & 6 \\[12pt]
    &   &   &   &   & 2 & 4 & 0 & & & & \longleftarrow & \text{remainder $= 24$} \\
    &   &   &   &   & 1 & 4 & 8 \\[12pt]
    &   &   &   &   &   & 9 & 2 & 0 \\
    &   &   &   &   &   & 8 & 8 & 8 \\[12pt]
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & 3 & 2 & 0 \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & 2 & 9 & 6 \\[12pt]
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 2 & 4 & 0 & \longleftarrow & \text{remainder $= 24$}
\end{array}
$$
Once we get the same remainder that we had at an earlier step, we're doing the same problem over again: what is $240$ divided by $148$?  And if we got $1.62$ last time, we still get $1.62$ and we still get the same remainder, $24$, and we're starting over again.

So the thing repears $0.37\ 162\ 162\ 162\ 162\ \ldots$.

But how do we know we must at some point get a remainder that we got before?

The answer is if you divide by $148$, the only possible remainders are $0,1,2,3,\ldots,147$.  The list of possible remainders doesn't go on forever, so at some point you get one you saw before.

Therefore in a rational number, the decimal expansion at some point starts repeating and keeps repeating.

That doesn't happen with your proposed decimal expansion, so it cannot be that of any rational number.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation with actual example of long division. This answer should serve as an example of effective pedagogy. It proves an important property of rational numbers in a rigorous manner without using generic symbols (although many would prefer rigor *with* symbolism and not without). +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : Thank you. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy can you *prove* that "this doesn't happen" ? After all, that is what Tom is asking.

Comment: @thepiercingarrow : That is _not_ what we was asking, as far as I can tell.    He made it clear that his decimal expansion does not terminate or repeat.  What he asked is whether it's rational, i.e. an integer over another integer.  In my answer I explained why a decimal expansion that does not terminate or repeat cannot be that of a rational number, i.e. not a ratio of two integers. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy he did not make it clear that his decimal expansion does not repeat. For all you know, the decimal could repeat every, say, x digits, where x is a very large number. The question asks for a *proof* that it doesn't repeat.

Comment: @thepiercingarrow : The question DOES NOT ask for a proof that it doesn't repeat.  The question asks for a proof that it's irrational.  "Irrational" is NOT defined to mean the decimal expansion does not repeat.  How it IS defined I've already explained in this thread. It is true that one often encounters ignorant people who think non-repeating (and non-terminating) is the definition of irrational number, but that is incorrect. $\qquad$